# How is the name "Gandalf" pronounced?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, names, gandalf

I've been reading answers to the question asking [how "Smaug" should be pronounced](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45350/is-smaug-pronounced-smog) and I was wondering, is there an authoritative answer to the pronunciation of "Gandalf"?

I first read *The Hobbit* when I was eight years old and I instinctively thought the name should be pronounced "Gan-dolf", the "-al-" being as in the word "salt". But in the films (especially the 1970s cartoon version) they pronounced it "Gan-dalf" with the "-al" pronounced as in "pal". This always sounded like an Americanism to me.

Comment: I never heard of salt being pronounced "solt", although I am an American and not a speaker of whatever your dialect is.  I always thought that Gandalf was pronounced "gand-alf".  I think that you might be influenced by Castle Gandolfo in Italy.

Comment: I mean "salt" as rhyming with "malt", halt" or "Walt". I've only visited the US a few times but I'm sure Mr. Disney's first name didn't have the same vowel sound as the first syllable of "fallacy".

Comment: In the first British audiobook versions of LOTR (a roommate had 'em), they pronounced Gandalf as Gan-daff, as in "half." I refused to believe that was correct, and will continue to do so. With my fingers in my ears if necessary.

Comment: Perhaps people who grew up on Shakespeare might pronounce it a little like "Falstaff"?

Comment: @M.A.Golding *I never heard of salt being pronounced "solt"*.  Really?  Then how do you pronounce it?

Comment: +1 to *pronounced "Gan-dolf", the "-al-" being as in the word "salt".*

Comment: @RonJohn Rhymes with "cult"

Comment: In my mind I have always pronounced it like if you would in english say gun-dullf (as the words gun and dull).

Comment: I'm an American, and yet I've always pronounced it "Gan-dolf".

Comment: I've always pronounced Gandalf as "GAND-ahf", and at least to my ear that's what Tolkien says in the clip below. The /l/ is silent (or vocalised, similar to the Received post-vocalic /r/), and the second /a/ is close to the /o/ in cot, but briefer.

Answer (score 74):

Who better to ask than the professor himself, here he is reading the opening to the Fellowship of the Ring. At [00:23](https://youtu.be/NLJ9z2bzAdQ) he says "'No' said Gandalf..."

Tolkien seems to pronounce it as most would expect (or at least as always seemed obvious to me), "gand" as in gander and "alf" as in Alfred or alpha. However, Tolkien seems to split the two syllables as "gan" and "dalf", with the syllable break on the 'd' as opposed to the 'a'.

According to the UK IPA (taken from the words [Gander](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gander) and [alpha](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alpha#English)) it would be something like /’ɡæn.dælf/ (Source for lettering from [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_pronunciation))

Similarly, [this clip](https://youtu.be/TQVi_DC9HvI?t=1m25s) from an interview with Sir Christopher Lee (who had met with Tolkien) shows that he pronounces it the same.

---

Wikipedia claims the IPA to be /ˈɡændɑːlf/, however this seems to be taken from *Appendix E - "Writing and Spelling"*. Which people have identified as not necessarily being accurate because they refer mostly to the ancient scripts as opposed to Westron. However from there it would suggest the following pronunciation:

> “has only the sound of g in give, get”

<sub>NB: The below has been amended due to a massive oversight by myself and the help from @Emil in the comments.</sub>

For the vowels they would've been pronounced as the 'a' in <s>machine</s> father which wikitionary suggest is an <s>/ə/</s> /ɑ/ (note these are still purely for Sindarin names):

> That is, the sounds were approximately those represented by i, e, a, o, u in English machine, were, father, for, brute, irrespective of quantity.

As for the "L"

> represents more or less the sound of English initial l, as in let.

The suggestion for "F" has been proven wrong by Tolkien as well as Sir Christopher and most other accounts.

> represents f, except at the end of words, where it is used to represent the sound of v (as in English of): Nindalf, Fladrif.

Comment: I think you are misreading the quote. You are supposed to pronounce “i” as in “machine”, and “a” as in “father”, not “a” as in “machine”.

Comment: He sounds just like Oliver Postgate!

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you're totally right!

Comment: If you want to stress the second syllable, write it like /ɡæn'dælf/. Most people I know pronounce it as /'ɡæn.dælf/, with the stress /'/ on the first syllable.

Comment: Having just listened to the Tolkien extract, he pronounces Gandalf as /'ɡæn.dælf/, with the stress on the first syllable and a syllable break (not stress) on the /d/. Your wording _stressing the 'd' at the beginning of the second syllable as opposed to the 'a'_ is confusing, as neither sound is stressed.

Comment: @CJDennis that was a remnant of an older version of the answer, your latter IPA transcription seems to be closest to Tolkien’s desired pronunciation.

Comment: That should all have been fixed now

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. Tolkien himself is the best source anyone could want!

Comment: There's some kind of missing text or formatting error after "it would suggest the".

Comment: @Miral fixed, thanks

Comment: The appendix is not very relevant, because Gandalf is not in a Middle-Earth language, neither Elvish nor Westron. As the other answer shows, Gandalf is a Nordic name. The "explanation" is that it's a translated version of whatever the Hobbits actually called him.

Comment: @Javier Gandalf from an out of universe perspective is Nordic, I did a quick google which suggested Gandalf was indeed the Westron name, with the Rohirrim using the name for him at times

Comment: AFAIK the Rohan language is also "translated". The problem is that mannish languages never appear directly in Lord of the Rings, only translated to their equivalents. Gandalf, much like Sam, Merry, Rivendell, Isengard and many others, is an European name and should be pronounced as such.

Comment: Either way the appendices only refer to the ancient languages, as mentioned in the answer, I merely left it in for “completeness sake” as some may ask for it from the comments. Whether it was in the language of the Rohirrim, old English or Mandarin, the guide is not accurate. @Javier

Comment: Funnily, Sir Christopher Lee pronounces it, in your video, just like a native German speaker would... certainly not at all like "Gander". Did I mention that I find Lee absolutely adorable, even (or especially) at the age of that clip...

Comment: Sounds just like how everyone in the movies pronounces it except Sean Bean, who pronounces everything like a dude from "The North".

Comment: I'm not certain Tolkien's pronunciation in this video should be taken as canon. The more common a character's name the more likely he is to fall back on a habitual pronunciation rather than a considered, more correct one; and Gandalf is one of the most common names in the book.

That said, where are you hearing anything like "alpha"? I'm hearing /ˈɡændɑf/ at 00:23

Comment: Like the last syllable of [tradeoff](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trade-off)

Comment: @Glen_b noted and fixed.

Comment: @AnoE I don't know how you pronounce the "gand" in "gander", but I would pronounce it exactly like Christopher Lee pronounces the "gand" in "gandalf"

Comment: @Edlothiad, not being a native speaker, I would probably pronounce it wrongly, but Merriam-Webster https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gander pronounces it differently from <strikethrough>Saruman</strikethrough> Lee.

Comment: @AnoE Argh... As I feared, that is a very typical american pronunciation... Although I'm not supposed to hold an opinion, blasphemous if you ask me. Lee and Tolkien would both have pronounced gander very similarly and pronounced gandalf with the same "gand"

Comment: @Edlothiad, unfortunately it is unlikely that we can find spoken Ganders from Tolkien and Lee, hence my suggestion to find another example, if there is one where UK and US agree. :-)

Comment: @AnoE given it’s the a that changes between American and British English, it is unlikely one will find one where they agree, hence the IPA and the two clips of reputable sources saying the name :)

Comment: *an interview with Sir Christopher Lee (who had met with Tolkien) shows that he pronounces it the same.* Seeing as Christopher Lee's only conversation with Tolkien consisted of just Lee saying "How do you do?" in a pub, I don't see how the fact that he "met" him is at all relevant here.

Comment: @ibid Probably deduced it from Tolkien's response. He tore apart all the sound Tolkien made in his response, and analysed his preferred pronunciation and reconstructed the word Gandalf from it. Obviously

Answer (score 12):

Tolkien took the name of Gandalf from *Gandalfr* in the list of dwarves in the *Voluspa* in the Elder Edda.

Since Gandalf means "cane/staff/wand elf", one can assume that "alf" might be pronounced like in Alfred which comes from Old English *aelfraed *or "elf counsel".   So I guess that Gandalf might be pronounced "gand alf" or "gand elf".

Here are discussions of how Gandalf should be pronounced:

http://forums.theonering.com/viewtopic.php?t=21292[3](http://forums.theonering.com/viewtopic.php?t=21292)

http://entmoot.tolkientrail.com/archive/index.php?t-569.html[4](http://entmoot.tolkientrail.com/archive/index.php?t-569.html)

In this Quora question one answer says that Gandalf should be pronounced "gand-olv".

Some of the other answers to the Quora question have links to video and audio clips with Gandalf pronounced.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-Gandalf[1](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-Gandalf)

Here is a link to another clip:

[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9ExokgIwMU)

Comment: Nice answer. I thought of "alf" meaning "elf", too.

Comment: The clip of Tolkien reading bits and pieces of LotR directly contradicts any /olf/ pronunciation: he clearly pronounces both a's the same way, and it's not like an /o/ at all.

Comment: I believe Gandalf is old Norse for "half-elven".

Comment: @Martha But it's very much like an /o/. The problem is that English has many /o/'s (and many /a/'s). The /a/ in Gandalf is much closer to the /o/ in pot than the /a/ in pat (at least in dialects affected by the cot–caught merger).

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Why? [It doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandalf_(mythology)).

Comment: @chepner: It seems you're right; at least it's "magic-wanf elf"; according to the source you're giving. I was told differently in Danish high school, however, but my teacher could well have been wrong. Still, "magic-wanf elf" is a strange name for a dwarf, where "half-elf" would make more sense. At any rate, according to the Norse dictionary I link to after this, "gandr" doesn't mean magic wand, but staff or stick, or possibly wolf. So Gandalf means "staff-elf" or "wolf-elf". https://archive.org/stream/oldnordiskordbog00jonsuoft/oldnordiskordbog00jonsuoft_djvu.txt

Answer (score 0):

According to the pronunciation section in Appendix E of Return of the King, it's said that "F represents f, except at the end of words, where it is used to represent the sound of v (as in English "of"): Nindalf, Fladrif.

Now I'm not sure to what the pronunciation guide applies, if it's just elvish stuff or if it's all names in the book, but if it's the latter, then Gandalf should at least be pronounced as if it was spelled Gandalv

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is noted in the first answer, as well as the fact this disagrees with the way Tolkien himself actually pronounced it.  Please only post a new answer if you have substantial new information to contribute, like another canon source that reinforces this pronunciation.